# Multiple End points or Single endpoint with multiple Web Method

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am a bit confused on the approach of creating web services.

Problem statement:
  Should i create a service with two end points like below

```
<jaxws:endpoint  id="stateService" implementor="com.service.StateServiceImpl" address="/stateservice" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="countryService" implementor="com.service.CountryServiceImpl" address="/countryservice" />
```

Or  create a single end point with two methods

```
public class Service{

@WebMethod(operationName="country", action="countryservice" )
public String countryService() {}

@WebMethod(operationName="state", action="stateservice" )
public String stateService() {}

}
```

The purpose  of both of my services or operations is different.

I am currently using Apache CXF with approach 1 i.e. separate end point.

what is the advantage of one over another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's mostly a question of how you want to advertise the relationship of the methods.  My rule of thumb here: if they are not related in any way, then separate endpoints.  If they operate on the same data (even if the operations are different), then it makes more sense to bundle as separate methods in the same endpoint, to telegraph that the data source is the same.

But, I'm sure there's a lot of variation to the answers you'll get ... this will ultimately boil down to what makes the most sense for you and your customers.

Comment: It makes as much sense as a client asking a contractor to install a jacuzzi on the 3rd floor of his house.  The contractor might have reasonable objections to the design, but ultimately it's the client's call.  If the client can pay for it and the necessary structural backfill, why should  the contractor refuse flatly?

Comment: There may be constraints on the customer side that ease implementation if the services are methods on a single endpoint.  Even if that's not architecturally beautiful, doesn't make it the wrong design given other constraints.

Comment: You keep deleting your comments. :)

Comment: My services are not related and i have created separate end points and now i am being asked to merge these end points to a single end point.  My point over here is that is it a good design practice, though client can pay for it :).

Comment: I'm being circumspect on purpose.  There are a lot of considerations besides elegance or academic purity.  When evaluating a decision, you should think about those as well.

Comment: Sorry for deletion, Also just to ease someones implementation should i change my design.

Comment: I am answering from a "professional services" point of view -- i.e. I have one project for one customer.  From this perspective, yes we alter designs to meet customer's specifications 100% of the time.  This answer would be different if we looked from a "mass market" point of view where no one customer controlled a plurality the project.  There, we rely more heavily on elegance and academics.

Comment: I agree that many of times we need to change design to meet customer's expectation. But  

a) Should the approach or design  we designed earlier be considered bad.
b) and how to convince the client that the current design  is not good and we should stick to same design

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40137/discussion-between-santosh-joshi-and-paulprogrammer)

Comment: The key to persuading the customer of anything is to first understand the real drivers for their request.  Then you can address the underlying conditions...  Maybe it's a training issue that can be resolved.  Maybe it's a technology constraint that just isn't going to change...  Maybe it's something else altogether.

Comment: Can't chat.  Corporate firewall. :(

Comment: Looks like i got the answer, Thanks for the discussions :)

Comment: If this was helpful, upvote -- if it is your answer please accept! :)